# Converting Code To LabView

Tags: labview

Recently I have been tasked with reworking a LabView program and was wondering if there is a way to write code in another language, and convert it to LabView syntax. I know it is possible to write DLL files and use those in LabView; however, once I leave the lab assistants want to be able to add to the program, so that approach would not be viable.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here: do you want to convert from another language because you already have code in another language, or because you'd rather not learn LabVIEW but you want to hand over LabVIEW code to other people who will then maintain it? Maybe the lab assistants should write this code themselves, not you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, no tools for that exist from National Instruments or from any third party. There are tools to convert LabVIEW code to C code, but going the other direction is a really hard problem to automate (the sequential nature of C code and it's use of pointers [or references in C++/C#] make it a bad fit for dataflow, so automated conversion would tend toward very poor performance and really hard to understand code). I did not find any tools, but I might have overlooked something. Generally, the two best places to check for tools are a) the [LabVIEW Tools Network](https://www.ni.com/labview-tools-network/) and b) the code repository on the [LAVA website](https://lavag.org).

Answer (score 0):

You can automate some programming tasks using LabVIEW scripting, but you have to write the LabVIEW code that translates from your chosen language. For instance, I have written LabVIEW code to create LabVIEW clusters from complicated C TypeDefs. But I have done this only because I am bringing flattened data into LabVIEW from C, and the C header files already exist.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can write your code in a different language and have it called in LabVIEW through a  DLL.  You would be using a Call Library Function Node.  Just be sure you set all your parameter correctly and it can work together.

If your writing from scratch.. I would recommend just doing it in LabVIEW since you can debug it much easier than running through a DLL.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can still post an answer regardless of post age - it doesn't really matter how old the post is.